# JsonArray Adding double brackets

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to add List of strings into Json Array Object and putting that object into JsonObject with key and Value as Json Array Object.
My sample code:

```
public static final List<String> COLUMN_NAMES =
    Arrays.asList(
        "String_1",
        "String_2",
        "String_3",
        "String_4");

JSONArray fields = JSONUtil.putAll(
        Constants.COLUMN_NAMES);
```

Output: `[["String_1","String_2","String_3","String_4"]]`

```
JSONObject body = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();

body.put("fields_key", **fields**);

final output : {"fields":[["String_1","String_2","String_3","String_4"]]}.
```

I am expecting the output result as below

```
{"fields":["String_1","String_2","String_3","String_4"]} - Removing extra brackets.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a `List` as first and only parameter to [`JSONUtil.putAll`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.liferay.portal/com.liferay.portal.kernel/6.4.0/com/liferay/portal/kernel/json/JSONUtil.html#putAll-java.lang.Object...-). But it has a variadic parameter list. Thus it accecepts an arbitrary number of parameters, it then puts into the resulting `JSONArray`. But it does not decompose the List you pass as first parameter. It just takes it as a whole and puts it as first element in the resulting JSONArray. Thus you get a nested list as result.

There are several possibilities.

1. Create the `JSONArray` from the values directly

   ```
   JSONArray fields = JSONUtil.putAll("string_1", "string_2", "string_3" ...);
   ```
2. Create the `JSONArray` directly from the list without the `JSONUtil`

   ```
   JSONArray fields = new JSONArray(COLUMN_NAMES);
   ```
3. Convert your list to an array before passing it to `putAll`

   ```
   JSONArray fields = JSONUtils.putAll(COLUMN_NAMES.toArray());
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired output where the array is not nested within another array in the JSON object, you should create a JSONArray directly from the list of strings instead of using JSONUtil.putAll(), which adds an extra layer of array. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve the desired result:

```
public static final List<String> COLUMN_NAMES =
    Arrays.asList(
        "String_1",
        "String_2",
        "String_3",
        "String_4");

// Create JSONArray directly from the list of strings
JSONArray fields = new JSONArray(COLUMN_NAMES);

JSONObject body = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
body.put("fields", fields);

// Convert JSONObject to string
String jsonString = body.toString();
System.out.println(jsonString);
```

This will produce the following JSON string:

```
{"fields":["String_1","String_2","String_3","String_4"]}
```

By directly passing the list of strings to the JSONArray constructor, you avoid creating an extra layer of array, resulting in the desired JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, some how it didnt worked when I tried to do

```
new JSONArray(COLUMN_NAMES)
```

But it did work when I use

```
public static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES  = {"string_1", "string_2", "string_3"}
```